# Cookie name repeated inside cookie value

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, cookies

I'm writing some values as cookies in my ASP.Net response which hosts my AngularJS app. Then I need to use those cookies values from the AJS app.

Asp:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack == false)
    {
        var accountNumber = Request["AccountNumber"] ?? "";
        AddCookie("AccountNumber", accountNumber);

        var email = Request["Email"] ?? "";
        AddCookie("Email", email);
    }
}
private void AddCookie(string cookieName, string cookieValue)
{
    var cookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName);
    cookie.Values.Add(cookieName, cookieValue);
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
```

Debug output when creating the cookie within the AddCookie function:

```html
?cookieValue
"moo"
?cookie
{System.Web.HttpCookie}
    Domain: null
    Expires: {2017/08/01 8:32:59 AM}
    HasKeys: true
    HttpOnly: false
    Name: "Email"
    Path: "/"
    Secure: false
    Shareable: false
    Value: "Email=moo"
    Values: {Email=moo}
```

Then in Angular:

```
function myController($log, $stateParams, $cookies) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.accNo = '';

    vm.accNo = $cookies.get('AccountNumber');
    $log.log(vm.accNo);

    vm.email = $cookies.get('Email');
    $log.log(vm.email);
}
```

The output of the log shows that the value of the cookies include the name so intead of having a `value == 123` the value of AccountNumber is `AccountNumber=123`.

See response from Fiddler, this confirms it:

Response sent 83 bytes of Cookie data:

> Set-Cookie: AccountNumber=AccountNumber=sfsdfsfs; expires=Mon,
>   31-Jul-2017 11:48:08 GMT; path=/

Response sent 64 bytes of Cookie data:

> Set-Cookie: Email=Email=sdfsf; expires=Mon, 31-Jul-2017 11:48:08 GMT;
>   path=/

Is this an ASP.Net quirk or am I doing something wrong here? 
I'd expect the cookie to be `AccountNumber=123` and not `AccountNumber=AccountNumer=123`.

Comment: Can you show us the URL you are requesting?

Comment: At the point where the AngulatJS controller is executed the url is http://localhost:7789/index.aspx#!/metertxns

Comment: I am wondering about how AccountNumber and Email are passed. If you debug the code, what do you see as Request["AccountNumber"]?

Comment: AccountNumber and Email are passed in from another page as a post to my host page. The values are coming in as expected without any fieldname prefixes. Also see updated post with code and debug values of the cookie creation.

Comment: FWIW the only way I could get the debug output formatted in this post was to put it inside a code snippet. It is not an executable code snippet but when using the normal code {} tags, it would only put the first line into the code block and the rest as text. Feel free to fix the format of the debug output if anyone knows how.

Comment: Neville, I am interested to know what is exactly posted to the server. I know you have the wrong values in the cookies, this question is all about that. But the cause is somewhere at the server or before posting to the server. I need to know what are the exact values of Request["AccountNumber"] and Request["Email"] on the server. Without those values I am afraid I cannot help you. The place where you debug the problem already exists, so we have to assume it comes from somewhere prior to the usage of the cookies.

Comment: Lajos, I understand your question and that is why I added the debug output and the AddCookie method. The variable named "email" gets its value directly from the request thus the value that was posted to the page. That value is "moo" and that is what was posted. It is then passed to the AddCookie method as cookieValue. cookieValue is printed in the debug as just "moo". Then System.Web.HttpCookie adds the value as "Email=moo". Either I am misunderstanding cookies in general or there is a bug in System.Web.HttpCookie?

Comment: The problematic part is "Email=moo". It seems that you pass Email=moo instead of moo. If that is the case, that would explain the issue you have.